# How to change or trigger back ground color whenever multiple text view change/update Asynchronies?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am trying to change background color Whenever Text view update but due to updating multiple text view background application stuck and not working due to main thread doing so much working can you help me here is my code how i can execute parallel without stuck application in android?
Note; getting live data from Realtime database when OnStar(); method calls

```
 
                  @Override
        public void onStart () {
        super.onStart();

//retriving data from firebase from here to 

        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            try {



                             gold9999rate = dataSnapshot.child("gold9999").getValue().toString();
                            //tempgold9999=gold9999rate;
                             gold9950rate = dataSnapshot.child("gold9950").getValue().toString();

                             silver9999rate = dataSnapshot.child("silver9999").getValue().toString();
                             silver9950rate = dataSnapshot.child("silver99").getValue().toString();

                             goldcomexbuyrate = dataSnapshot.child("goldcomexbuy").getValue().toString();
                             goldcomexsellrate = dataSnapshot.child("goldcomexsell").getValue().toString();
                             goldcomexhighrate = dataSnapshot.child("goldcomexhigh").getValue().toString();
                             goldcomexlowrate = dataSnapshot.child("goldcomexlow").getValue().toString();

                            silvercomexbuyrate = dataSnapshot.child("silvercomexbuy").getValue().toString();
                            silvercomexsellrate = dataSnapshot.child("silvercomexsell").getValue().toString();
                            silvercomexhighrate = dataSnapshot.child("silvercomexhigh").getValue().toString();
                            silvercomexlowrate = dataSnapshot.child("silvercomexlow").getValue().toString();

                            inrcomexbuyrate = dataSnapshot.child("inrcomexbuy").getValue().toString();
                            inrcomexsellrate = dataSnapshot.child("inrcomexsell").getValue().toString();
                            inrcomexhighrate = dataSnapshot.child("inrcomexhigh").getValue().toString();
                            inrcomexlowrate = dataSnapshot.child("inrcomexlow").getValue().toString();

                            goldmcxbuyrate = dataSnapshot.child("goldmcxbuy").getValue().toString();
                            goldmcxsellrate = dataSnapshot.child("goldmcxsell").getValue().toString();
                            goldmcxhighrate = dataSnapshot.child("goldmcxhigh").getValue().toString();
                            goldmcxlowrate = dataSnapshot.child("goldmcxlow").getValue().toString();

                            silvermcxbuyrate = dataSnapshot.child("silvermcxbuy").getValue().toString();
                            silvermcxsellrate = dataSnapshot.child("silvermcxsell").getValue().toString();
                            silvermcxhighrate = dataSnapshot.child("silvermcxhigh").getValue().toString();
                            silvermcxlowrate = dataSnapshot.child("silvermcxlow").getValue().toString();

//till here then after 
//from here i am setting on textview  
                            gold9999.setText(gold9999rate);


                            gold9950.setText(gold9950rate);

                            silver9999.setText(silver9999rate);
                            silver9950.setText(silver9950rate);
                            goldcomexbuy.setText(goldcomexbuyrate);


                            goldcomexsell.setText(goldcomexsellrate);


                            goldcomexhighlow.setText(goldcomexhighrate + "/" + goldcomexlowrate);

                            silvercomexbuy.setText(silvercomexbuyrate);
                            silvercomexsell.setText(silvercomexsellrate);
                            silvercomexhighlow.setText(silvercomexhighrate + "/" + silvercomexlowrate);

                            inrcomexbuy.setText(inrcomexbuyrate);
                            inrcomexsell.setText(inrcomexsellrate);
                            inrcomexhighlow.setText(inrcomexhighrate + "/" + inrcomexlowrate);

                            mcxgoldbuy.setText(goldmcxbuyrate);
                            mcxgoldsell.setText(goldmcxsellrate);
                            mcxgoldhighlow.setText(goldmcxhighrate + "/" + goldmcxlowrate);

                            mcxsilverbuy.setText(silvermcxbuyrate);
                            mcxsilversell.setText(silvermcxsellrate);
                            mcxsilverhighlow.setText(silvermcxhighrate + "/" + silvermcxlowrate);

//till here now after i am trying to convert string value into integer & float after store value in static previous vales compare with next coming values 
//here i am trying to using thread for run and  update background with colors 
//here i want to achieve change background color without lagg or stuck applcation while changing background color  
  Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                            prevgold9999 = Integer.parseInt(gold9999rate);
                            prevgold9950 = Integer.parseInt(gold9950rate);
                            prevsilver9999 = Integer.parseInt(silver9999rate);
                            prevsilver9950 = Integer.parseInt(silver9950rate);
                            prevmcxgoldbuy = Integer.parseInt(goldmcxbuyrate);
                            prevmcxgoldsell = Integer.parseInt(goldmcxsellrate);
                            prevmcxsilverbuy = Integer.parseInt(silvermcxbuyrate);
                            prevmcxsilversell = Integer.parseInt(silvermcxsellrate);
                            prevgoldcomexbuy = Float.parseFloat(goldcomexbuyrate);
                            prevgoldcomexsell = Float.parseFloat(goldcomexsellrate);
                            prevsilvercomexbuy = Float.parseFloat(silvercomexbuyrate);
                            prevsilvercomexsell = Float.parseFloat(silvercomexsellrate);
                            previnrcomexbuy = Float.parseFloat(inrcomexbuyrate);
                            previnrcomexsell = Float.parseFloat(inrcomexsellrate);

                            

                int nextgold9999=Integer.parseInt(gold9999rate);
                int nextgold9950=Integer.parseInt(gold9950rate);
                int nextsilver9999=Integer.parseInt(silver9999rate);
                int nextsilver9950=Integer.parseInt(silver9950rate);
                int nextmcxgoldbuy=Integer.parseInt(goldmcxbuyrate);
                int nextmcxgoldsell=Integer.parseInt(goldmcxsellrate);
                int nextmcxsilverbuy=Integer.parseInt(silvermcxbuyrate);
                int nextmcxsilversell=Integer.parseInt(silvermcxsellrate);
                float nextgoldcomexbuy= Float.parseFloat(goldcomexbuyrate);
                float nextgoldcomexsell=Float.parseFloat(goldcomexsellrate);
                float nextsilvercomexbuy=Float.parseFloat(silvercomexbuyrate);
                float nextsilvercomexsell=Float.parseFloat(silvercomexsellrate);
                float nextinrcomexbuy=Float.parseFloat(inrcomexbuyrate);
                float  nextinrcomexsell=Float.parseFloat(inrcomexsellrate);


                  
 requireActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {

                     
                        gold9999.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                            @Override
                            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                                if (nextgold9999 > prevgold9999) {
                                 
                                    gold9999.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.rate_green));
                                } else if (nextgold9999 < prevgold9999) {
                                    gold9999.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));

                                } else if (nextgold9999 == prevgold9999) {
                                    gold9999.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bg_navigation_gray));
                                    // 
                                }
                                prevgold9999 = nextgold9999;

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                            }
                        });

                        gold9950.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                            @Override
                            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                                if (nextgold9950 > prevgold9950) {
                                    gold9950.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.rate_green));
          
                                } else if (nextgold9950 < prevgold9950) {
                                    gold9950.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                                    
                                } else if (nextgold9950 == prevgold9950) {
                                    gold9950.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bg_navigation_gray));
                                    
                                }
                                prevgold9950 = nextgold9950;

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                            }
                        });

                        silver9999.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                            @Override
                            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                                if (nextsilver9999 > prevsilver9999) {
                                    silver9999.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.rate_green));
                                    // 
                                } else if (nextsilver9999 < prevsilver9999) {
                                    silver9999.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                                    
                                } else if (nextsilver9999 == prevsilver9999) {
                                    silver9999.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bg_navigation_gray));
                                   
                                }
                                prevsilver9999 = nextsilver9999;

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                            }
                        });

                        silver9950.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                            @Override
                            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                                if (nextsilver9950 > prevsilver9950) {
                                    silver9950.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.rate_green));
                                   
                                } else if (nextsilver9950 < prevsilver9950) {
                                    silver9950.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                                    
                                } else if (nextsilver9950 == prevsilver9950) {
                                    silver9950.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bg_navigation_gray));
                                    
                                }
                                prevsilver9950 = nextsilver9950;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                            }
                        });

                        mcxgoldbuy.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                            @Override
                            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                                if (nextmcxgoldbuy > prevmcxgoldbuy) {
                                    mcxgoldbuy.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.rate_green));
                                    
                                } else if (nextmcxgoldbuy < prevmcxgoldbuy) {
                                    mcxgoldbuy.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                                    
                                } else if (nextmcxgoldbuy == prevmcxgoldbuy) {
                                    mcxgoldbuy.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bg_navigation_gray));
                                    
                                }
                                prevmcxgoldbuy = nextmcxgoldbuy;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                            }
                        });

                        mcxgoldsell.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                            @Override
                            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                                if (nextmcxgoldsell > prevmcxgoldsell) {
                                    mcxgoldsell.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.rate_green));
                                    
                                } else if (nextmcxgoldsell < prevmcxgoldsell) {
                                    mcxgoldsell.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                                    
                                } else if (nextmcxgoldsell == prevmcxgoldsell) {
                                    mcxgoldsell.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bg_navigation_gray));
                                    
                                }
                                prevmcxgoldsell = nextmcxgoldsell;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                            }
                        });


                        mcxsilverbuy.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                            @Override
                            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                                if (nextmcxsilverbuy > prevmcxsilverbuy) {
                                    mcxsilverbuy.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.rate_green));
                                    
                                } else if (nextmcxsilverbuy < prevmcxsilverbuy) {
                                    mcxsilverbuy.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                                    
                                } else if (nextmcxsilverbuy == prevmcxsilverbuy) {
                                    mcxsilverbuy.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bg_navigation_gray));
                                    
                                }
                                prevmcxsilverbuy = nextmcxsilverbuy;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                            }
                        });

                        mcxsilversell.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                            @Override
                            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                                if (nextmcxsilversell > prevmcxsilversell) {
                                    mcxsilversell.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.rate_green));
                                    
                                } else if (nextmcxsilversell < prevmcxsilversell) {
                                    mcxsilversell.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                                    
                                } else if (nextmcxsilversell == prevmcxsilversell) {
                                    mcxsilversell.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bg_navigation_gray));
                                    
                                }
                                prevmcxsilversell = nextmcxsilversell;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                            }
                        });

                        goldcomexbuy.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                            @Override
                            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                                if (nextgoldcomexbuy > prevgoldcomexbuy) {
                                    goldcomexbuy.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.rate_green));
                                    
                                } else if (nextgoldcomexbuy < prevgoldcomexbuy) {
                                    goldcomexbuy.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                                  
                                } else if (nextgoldcomexbuy == prevgoldcomexbuy) {
                                    goldcomexbuy.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bg_navigation_gray));
                                    
                                }
                                prevgoldcomexbuy = nextgoldcomexbuy;

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                            }
                        });


                        goldcomexsell.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                            @Override
                            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                                if (nextgoldcomexsell > prevgoldcomexsell) {
                                    goldcomexsell.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.rate_green));
                                    
                                } else if (nextgoldcomexsell < prevgoldcomexsell) {
                                    goldcomexsell.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                                    
                                } else if (nextgoldcomexsell == prevgoldcomexsell) {
                                    goldcomexsell.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bg_navigation_gray));
                                    
                                }
                                prevgoldcomexsell = nextgoldcomexsell;

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                            }
                        });

                        silvercomexbuy.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                            @Override
                            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                                if (nextsilvercomexbuy > prevsilvercomexbuy) {
                                    silvercomexbuy.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.rate_green));
                                    
                                } else if (nextsilvercomexbuy < prevsilvercomexbuy) {
                                    silvercomexbuy.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                                    
                                } else if (nextsilvercomexbuy == prevsilvercomexbuy) {
                                    silvercomexbuy.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bg_navigation_gray));
                                    
                                }
                                prevsilvercomexbuy = nextsilvercomexbuy;

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                            }
                        });

                        silvercomexsell.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                            @Override
                            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                                if (nextsilvercomexsell > prevsilvercomexsell) {
                                    silvercomexsell.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.rate_green));
                                    
                                } else if (nextsilvercomexsell < prevsilvercomexsell) {
                                    silvercomexsell.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));

 1. `List item`

                                    
                                } else if (nextsilvercomexsell == prevsilvercomexsell) {
                                    silvercomexsell.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bg_navigation_gray));
                                    
                                }
                                prevsilvercomexsell = nextsilvercomexsell;

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                            }
                        });

                        inrcomexbuy.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                            @Override
                            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                                if (nextinrcomexbuy > previnrcomexbuy) {
                                    inrcomexbuy.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.rate_green));
                                    
                                } else if (nextinrcomexbuy < previnrcomexbuy) {
                                    inrcomexbuy.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                                    
                                } else if (nextinrcomexbuy == previnrcomexbuy) {
                                    inrcomexbuy.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bg_navigation_gray));
                                                                    }
                                previnrcomexbuy = nextinrcomexbuy;

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                            }
                        });

                        inrcomexsell.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                            @Override
                            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

                                if (nextinrcomexsell > previnrcomexsell) {
                                    inrcomexsell.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.rate_green));
                                    
                                } else if (nextinrcomexsell < previnrcomexsell) {
                                    inrcomexsell.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                                    
                                } else if (nextinrcomexsell == previnrcomexsell) {
                                    inrcomexsell.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.bg_navigation_gray));
                                    
                                }
                                previnrcomexsell = nextinrcomexsell;

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

                            }
                        });
              }
                        
                });

                    }
                     });
                        t.start();



            }catch (Exception e){

                e.printStackTrace();


            }


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Log.i("TAP","something wrong");
                    String err=databaseError.toString();
                    Toast toast=Toast.makeText(getContext(), err, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.setMargin(50,50);
                    toast.show();

                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: i want achieving textview color should be change of all textview parallelly/uniformly  at same time please help me

Comment: Where in the program are you retrieving data? if that is also on the main thread, try moving it to a background thread.

Comment: i have update code with comments please see once again mention where i am retrieving data from firebase and where i am trying to set background color for instant basically trying to achieve change background color  of all text view whenever it update or change values  at same time but its changing only any one text view color randomly

Comment: Have you checked to make sure you are receiving all the data?  If you are, then might I suggest looking into kotlin coroutines?

Comment: yes am receiving all data application working fine but all doing on main thread i think and  i want to change background color according vale decease or increase at that time only rest of time should be default color value